# Unity file.exists doesnt return true for an existing file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity c#, the file.exists always returns false.

```
public class StartMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject playButton;
public GameObject loadButton;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    // generate correct pathname format for device
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Data");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "Aralimar.data");

    Debug.Log(path);
    Debug.Log(System.IO.File.Exists("path"));

    if (System.IO.File.Exists("path"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Save game exists");
        playButton.SetActive(true);
        loadButton.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

The file exists and if I paste the path from the debug log into Windows explorer it opens without a problem. A related function LoadGameData called directly from the startmenu which uses exactly the same path formation works without any problem so Unity can find and open the file.

```
 public void LoadGameData()
{
    // generate correct pathname format for device
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Data");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "Aralimar.data");

    Debug.Log("Loading data from " + path);

    // load xml file into GameData
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameData));
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    gameData = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream) as GameData;
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Debug statements:

```
C:/Users/*myname*/AppData/LocalLow/Wyeknott/Aralimar\Data\Aralimar.data

False

Loading data from C:/Users/*myname*/AppData/LocalLow/Wyeknott/Aralimar\Data\Aralimar.data
```

System details: Windows 10, unity 2017.3.0f3

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `System.IO.File.Exists(path))`? Notice I removed double quotes around `path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.IO.File.Exists("path")` change to `System.IO.File.Exists(path)`

`"path"` is ordinary string, and `path` without quotes is a reference to your variable.

This is as simple as possible. Not sure where you came from to C# but I will recommend to read some books or tutorials about it

Comment: Thank you. I was going blind looking for that.

Comment: Nice. If your question was answered, please accept the answer